# ModuleNotFoundError virtual environment pythonanywhere in scheduled task

Tags: django, scheduled-tasks, pythonanywhere

I am trying to schedule a task, but when running the script I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clients'
```

Even this is an installed app within my django project.
I already added a hashbang/shebang as:

1. #!/usr/bin/venv python3.9
2. #!/usr/bin/python3.9

Either option gets me the same error message. I think my code for the schedule task is good, but here it is anyways:

```
cd /home/myusername/myproject/maintenance && workon venv && python3.9 mantenimientosemanal.py
```

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does your script look like?  What is this ```clients``` module?  Is it part of your code or some external module?

Comment: Try using this `source virtualenvwrapper.sh && workon venv && python /home/myusername/myproject/maintenance/mantenimientosemanal.py` (see: [this help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/VirtualEnvInScheduledTasks/#the-more-complicated-case-with-environment-variables)).

Comment: @ewong clients is a django model installed in settings.py.

Comment: @caseneuve thanks for the code line, I have tried this already as well as it but  with different syntaxes, however the problem is that the code does not find the "module" clients which is a model.

Comment: After reading, I am thinking it is something related to WSGI file and the location of the script file when being executed from the virtual environment, bad news I have not found a solution yet...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after reading a lot, for some reason there is something related to WSGI, sys.path that I don't know yet but I found out this can be solved by creating a custom django-admin commands and then running this python manage.py mycustomcommand as a scheduled task and voila!! It worked!! Thanks and hope this help others.